# Extract log-level from logs, logstrash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Can any one please help me to extract log `log-level` from following logs -

```
2017-05-16 11:52:37,962|DEBUG|logging.WorkerThread|pool-2-thread-1|RequestId:31|ServiceInstanceId:31|VirtualServerName:31|ServiceName:31|InstanceUUID:31|AlertSeverity:31|ServerIPAddress:31|ServerFQDN:31|RemoteHost:31|ClassName:31|Timer:31| This is debug
```

I am using bellow pattern to generate it -

```
value="%date{ISO8601,UTC}|%.-5level|%logger|%thread|%X{LogType}|%X{Component}|%X{RequestId}|%X{ServiceInstanceId}|%X{VirtualServerName}|%X{ServiceName}|%X{InstanceUUID}|%X{AlertSeverity}|%X{ServerIPAddress}|%X{ServerFQDN}|%X{RemoteHost}|%X{ClassName}|%X{Timer}| %msg%n" />
```

I am expecting something like this -

```
{
     "message" => "2017-05-16 11:52:37,962|DEBUG|logging.WorkerThread|pool-2-thread-1|RequestId:31|ServiceInstanceId:31|VirtualServerName:31|ServiceName:31|InstanceUUID:31|AlertSeverity:31|ServerIPAddress:31|ServerFQDN:31|RemoteHost:31|ClassName:31|Timer:31| This is debug",
     "timestamp" => "2017-05-16 11:52:37,962",
     "log-level" => "DEBUG",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Data}\|%{WORD:LogLevel}\|%{NOTSPACE:WorkerThread}\|pool\-%{WORD:PoolNumber}\-thread\-%{WORD:ThreadNumber}\|RequestId\:%{NUMBER:RequestId}\|ServiceInstanceId\:%{NUMBER:ServiceInstance}\|VirtualServerName\:%{NUMBER:VirtualServerName}\|ServiceName\:%{NUMBER:ServiceName}\|InstanceUUID\:%{NUMBER:InstanceUUID}\|AlertSeverity\:%{NUMBER:AlertSeverity}\|ServerIPAddress\:%{NUMBER:ServerIPAddress}\|ServerFQDN\:%{NUMBER:ServerFQDN}\|RemoteHost\:%{NUMBER:RemoteHost}\|ClassName\:%{NUMBER:ClassName}\|Timer\:%{NUMBER:Timer}\|%{GREEDYDATA:Text}
```

This will extract all your fields. based in the log line example given.

Comment: Hi @Rabbit, 

Thank you so much, it is working according to my expectation.
I am completely new to this `grok` patterns, can you please provide me some source where I can master on it?

Thank you so much

Comment: Hey @CRSardar try the following links: 
[grok patterns](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns) 
[grok debbuger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)
[logstash doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

Comment: Thanks @Rabbit,
Little more help required?
pipeline is as follows - 
Filebeat(simply monitoring .txt file)>Logstash>Elasticsearch.
Using `gork` as you suggested, I see  Elasticsearch is saving data as follows -
`"hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "logstash-2017.05.17",
        "_type" : "log",
        "_id" : "tEFlvHP",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "LogLeve_Chitta" : "ERROR",
          "ClassName_Chitta" : "47",
          "RequestId_Chitta" : "47",
          "ServerIPAddress_Chitta" : "47",`

Comment: `"WorkerThread_Chitta" : "logging.WorkerThread",
          "message_Chitta" : " OMG what a horrific Error",
          "ServerFQDN_Chitta" : "47",
          "Data_Chitta" : "1988-04-28 01:57:21,299",
          "Timer_Chitta" : "47",          
          "PoolNumber_Chitta" : "2",
          "RemoteHost_Chitta" : "47",
          "ServiceName_Chitta" : "47",
          "VirtualServerName_Chitta" : "47",
          "AlertSeverit_Chittay" : "47",
          "ThreadNumber_Chitta" : "1",
          "ServiceInstance_Chitta" : "47",
          "InstanceUUID_Chitta" : "47",`

Comment: `"message" : "1988-04-28 01:57:21,299|...",
    "source" : "C:\\log\\MSO\\ERROR.log",
          "type" : "log",
    "@version" : "1",
          "beat" : {
            "hostname" : "CHITTARS02",
            "name" : "CHITTARS02",
            "version" : "5.4.0"
          },
          "host" : "CHITTARS02",
    "offset" : 777,
    "input_type" : "log",
    "tags" : [
            "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
          ],
    "@timestamp" : "2017-05-17T10:16:19.972Z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: FileBeat is adding following fields - 
`"message" : "1988-04-28 01:57:21,299|...",
    "source" : "C:\\log\\MSO\\ERROR.log",
          "type" : "log",
    "@version" : "1",
          "beat" : {
            "hostname" : "CHITTARS02",
            "name" : "CHITTARS02",
            "version" : "5.4.0"
          },
          "host" : "CHITTARS02",
    "offset" : 777,
    "input_type" : "log",
    "tags" : [
            "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
          ],
    "@timestamp" : "2017-05-17T10:16:19.972Z"`

Comment: Is there any ways to exclude following -
`message, source, type, @version, beat, host, offset, input_type, tags, @timestamp` ?

I  don't want those fields & it's corresponding values to be stored in Elasticsearch

Comment: I believe you can use the mutate plugin. [mutate plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html)